# Module using another function of the same module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have something like this:

- MyModule

  - `index.js`
  - `myFunction1.js`
  - `myFunction2.js`

In `index.js` file i'm exporting all modules function (`myFunction1` and `myFunction2`). But, in `myFunction2` I use `myFunction1`.

If I import the index (all the module) and call it like `MyModule.myFunction1` inside `myFunction2`, I get an error (function does not exists).

If I import `myFunction1.js` and call it like `myFunction1()`, I can't make an Stub of it when I'm going to test it.

Any aproach to do something like this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Post your code! More than one pattern can be used to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
//////////////////////
// File: ./index.js //
//////////////////////
const myFunction1 = require('./myFunction1.js');
const myFunction2 = require('./myFunction2.js');

module.exports = {
    myFunction1,
    myFunction2
};

////////////////////////////
// File: ./myFunction1.js //
////////////////////////////
module.exports = function1(x){
    return x;
};

////////////////////////////
// File: ./myFunction2.js //
////////////////////////////
const myFunction1 = require('./myFunction1.js'); // or dropping the `.js` require('./myFunction1')
module.exports = function2(x){
    return myFunction1(x);
};
```

Comment: What i'm trying to acomplish is that i can call the function using the object, so I can test it without problem by making an stub. Something like mymodule.function2. I'm researching but seems that it cannot be done in nodejs.

Comment: You want to test `function1` but not test `function2`, and instead, creating a mock for it?

Answer (score 1):

Diego's answer works fine, except that OP seems to want to use index.js in myFunction2.js. Use the same code as Diego's for index.js

for index.js (same as Diego's)

```
const myFunction1 = require('./myFunction1.js');
const myFunction2 = require('./myFunction2.js');

module.exports = {
    myFunction1,
    myFunction2
};
```

for myFunction1.js (small fix)

```
module.exports = function function1(x){
    return x;
};
```

for myFunction2.js (changed to include index.js):

```
const MyModule = require('./index.js'); 
module.exports = function function2(x){
    return MyModule.myFunction1(x);
};
```

and a test.js :

```
const myFunction2 = require('./myFunction2.js');

console.log(myFunction2(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```
let fnk1 = (a) => {
  return a + ' 1 '
}
let fnk2 = (a) => {
  return fnk1(a)
}
module.exports = {
 fnk1,
 fnk2
}
```

test.js

```
let Mymodule = require('./index')
console.log(Mymodule.fnk2('argValue'));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to avoid: The functions in the same file. But thanks for the try.

Comment: @SantiagoMendozaRamirez can you drop a bit more detailed modules pseudo code example of you want to achieve ? Had similar problems while have been learning es6. Those problems were reduced by establishing a practice around a [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) concept.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It would be better if they were in the same file.

```
module.exports.myFunction1 = function() {
...
}

module.exports.myFunction2 = function() {
   module.exports.myFunction1()
}
```

If you need them to be in separate files, you can require function1 inside of the function2 file. The thing is, each file is its own module. From the Node.js docs:

> Node.js has a simple module loading system. In 
>   Node.js, files and modules are in one-to-one correspondence (each file
>   is treated as a separate module).

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid. I want each function in his own file. Thanks for node.js doc quote.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myFunction1 = require('./myFunction1.js');
const myFunction2 = require('./myFunction2.js');
module.exports = {
    myFunction1:myFunction1,
    myFunction2:function(x){
      return myFunction2(x,myFunction1);
    }
}
////////////////////////////
// File: ./myFunction1.js //
////////////////////////////
module.exports = function1(x){
    return x;
};

////////////////////////////
// File: ./myFunction2.js //
////////////////////////////

module.exports = function2(x,myFunction1){
    return myFunction1(x);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not clear because you did not post your code. Since, here is a working solution for your problem:

**MyModule.js:**

```
function myFunction1() {
  console.log("- I am myFunction1")
}

function myFunction2() {
  console.log("- I am myFunction2")
  myFunction1()
}

module.exports = {
  myFunction1,
  myFunction2
}
```

**index.js**

```
const MyModule = require('./MyModule')

console.log("Call myFunction1")
MyModule.myFunction1()
console.log("Call myFunction1")
MyModule.myFunction2()
```

If you execute `node index.js`, you get the following output:

```
Call myFunction1
- I am myFunction1
Call myFunction2
- I am myFunction2
- I am myFunction1
```